# What's the difference between `onClick` and `onContentClick` in konvajs

Tags: konvajs

`Stage` have both `click` and `contentClick` and others, I check the doc and no place to explain their differences.

`contentClick` just a alias or have some particular function?

Comment: the event order like this:
 `stage normal mouse down` ->
 `stage content mouse down` ->
 `stage normal mouse up` ->
 `stage normal click` ->
 `stage content mouse up` ->
 `stage content click`

Comment: how did you find that out ?

Comment: I just add all handlers in `Stage` then trigger mouse click.

Comment: I have previously wondered if there is a simple piece of JS to hook in to all events as they fire. I find the law-of-unintended-event-sequence quite often catches me out in UI development.

Comment: As far as I know, no way to catch all events except register one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `content[Something]` events are out of internal hit detection flow and out of event bubbling flow.

When you listen to `contentClick` event you can't know what shape is clicked, because `e.target` is undefined.

**Historic note:**

Some time ago `click` event was not triggering when you click on empty space of the stage. So that is the case where `contentClick` event was useful. But that behavior is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: I have another question about the parameter: event. It's method seems don't match the standard [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), when I call `stopPropagation` on it caused an error.

Comment: Because it is not a standard event. Standart event is saved inside "evt" property.